# svn command line (Windows, from TortoiseSVN): no output from "svn status"?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Started using TortoiseSVN, one issue buggers me: I don't see ovelray for non-versioned files.
I've read that this can happen (still, it sucks), so I moved to the next level: use command line.

`svn info` works fine, but `svn status` (from the very same directory) gives no output at all.

What's wrong?

Comment: When there's no modification to versionned files, you won't have any status.

Answer (score 9):

By default `svn status` will return nothing from the command line if no modifications have been made to the working copy.

If you would like see the status of files (including non-versioned) you can add the verbose flag to the command line: `svn status -v`.

This will list the repository with the status of each file, revision number, and last person who committed changes.  Non-versioned files will be marked with a "?".

Comment: Note: ignored files won't be shown with a plain `svn status` either.  You'd need to use `svn status --no-ignore` to see them--though you don't generally want to.